# NSData got displays error like "NSData response = <Invalid PC in frame.>" while downloading Images from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uiimageview, nsdata

I have got error like "NSData response = ".
  I am using following Request method:

```
+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error;
```

Actually I am downloading image from server and display in UIImageView. I am downloading images using "dispatch_async", when image will be downloaded then move it to the Main Queue. 
  Here, I am displaying the image in UIImageView. But here application is crashed.

When I print crash report it displays `"NSData response = <Invalid PC in frame.>"` 
Sometimes I got this issue and sometimes the Application works perfectly without crash.

What should I do?

Comment: can u post ur full code?

Comment: What makes you sure you get actually image data in the returned NSData object? Are you checking the error parameter and the response?